# Impossible average according to max?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So i'm trying to get the min, max and average from a list of times but doing min max and average on column N gives impossible numbers can someone explain what's going on?

[image] -

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13c584elcCujApE55Nl9J9RlHTHcVk0iU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Min, Max, Average will return just number of time value. You need to format the resulting cells as time format. Or use can use `TEXT()` function.

Comment: @Harun24HR what do you mean? Both the column containing the times and the results cells are formatted to time?

Comment: Yes both cell should be formatted as time otherwise you will get some value instead of time.

Comment: @Harun24HR yeah they're already both formatted as time but i'm still getting those weird results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your data and problem, you cn format the calculations as Excel's equivalent of `Duration`

[image]

*You could use the same format for `Time in Yard`, but it won't make any difference to the calculation -- just make your report more clear*

```
[h]:mm
```

[image]

Comment: Rosenfield Ahh that seems correct thank you :D